# Custom TaskStack finishes parent activity from notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, back-stack

I'm having problems with using `TaskStack` for notifications. I'm trying to keep the navigational flow of my app when a notification is tapped.

The navigation style of my app is like:

`PrincipalActivity` (parent) → `SecondaryActivity` (child)

Sometimes a GCM service can push notifications that starts `SecondaryActivity`. An instance of `PrincipalActivity` may or not exist so I implement a custom PendingIntent from a `TaskStack` (see below). This works when `PrincipalActivity` is paused or closed.

The problem comes when the user clicks on the notification while `PrincipalActivity` in the foreground: `PendingIntent` calls `PrincipalActivity.onDestroy()` and creates a new stack of activities losing all the data.

**Service** pushes the notification:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SecondaryActivity.class);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(SecondaryActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

mNotificationManager.notify(id, mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.hitsbam.geotalk.Principal"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/principal_titulo"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" />

<activity
    android:name="com.hitsbam.geotalk.Secondary"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/peticiones_titulo"
    android:parentActivityName=".Principal" />
```

I tried with the flags of `PendingIntent` (`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`) and experimented with different `launch_mode` for the activities in the manifest (`singleTask`, `singleTop`, `singleInstance`), but no luck.

How can I create the aforementioned custom `TaskStack` with activity and parents when that parent is already in the foreground, and without losing the data? (Ideally, reusing the activity in the stack?)